# How do I use sharppcap to send packets on loopback devices

Tags: c#, sharppcap

I tried to send packets to the local application, via loopback device,An error occurred when I sent packets on the loopback device[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee8ok.png)

SharpPcap.PcapException:“Can't send packet: send error: PacketSendPacket failed: The request is not supported.(50)

How do I send packets on a loopback device

All network devices except the loopback device can send packets properly